# How can I fix this networkx graph layout so it is easy to read?

Tags: jupyter, networkx

I have the following directed graph (see edges below), where each pair of numbers is a node ('1 3' for example). I am trying to graph it on Jupyter using the networkx graph layouts, and it keeps coming out super ugly. I have tried circular, spring, and other layouts. The best so far has been kamada_kawai_layout. I have tried changing parameters of the arrows and nodes and all I get is a bunch of overlap. The best I've been able to get is below.
Please help! I just want to be able to see all of the nodes and edges with no overlap.
[image]```
[('1 1', '1 3'), ('1 1', '1 4'), ('1 3', '1 5'), ('1 3', '3 3'), ('1 3', '3 4'), ('1 4', '1 2'),
('1 4', '1 3'), ('1 4', '3 4'), ('1 4', '4 4'), ('1 2', '1 1'), ('1 5', '1 7'), ('3 3', '3 5'),
('3 4', '2 3'), ('3 4', '3 3'), ('3 4', '4 5'), ('4 4', '2 4'), ('4 4', '3 4'), ('1 7', '3 7'),
('1 7', '4 7'), ('1 6', '1 8'), ('3 7', '5 7'), ('4 7', '2 7'), ('4 7', '3 7'), ('2 2', '2 3'),
('2 3', '1 3'), ('2 3', '2 6'), ('2 6', '2 4'), ('2 6', '2 5'), ('2 6', '2 7'), ('2 6', '3 6'),
('2 4', '1 4'), ('2 5', '2 8'), ('2 5', '3 5'), ('3 5', '3 7'), ('3 5', '5 6'), ('2 7', '1 7'),
('2 7', '2 8'), ('3 6', '3 8'), ('3 6', '6 6'), ('4 5', '4 7'), ('5 6', '4 5'), ('5 6', '5 5'),
('5 6', '5 7'), ('5 6', '6 8'), ('6 6', '4 6'), ('6 6', '5 6'), ('6 6', '6 7'), ('5 7', '5 8'),
('5 7', '7 7'), ('4 6', '4 8'), ('5 5', '5 8'), ('6 7', '6 8'), ('6 7', '7 8')]

Answer (score 0):

you could use the node names as positions on a 2d grid:

```
# G is the graph object 

pos = {}
for node in G.nodes:
    pos[node] = [int(a) for a in node.split(' ')]

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos)
```